# INSERT SQL in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a Java application and I want to use SQL database. I have a class for my connection :

```
public class SQLConnection{
    private static String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/table";
    private static String user = "postgres";
    private static String passwd = "toto";
    private static Connection connect;
    public static Connection getInstance(){
        if(connect == null){
            try {
                connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Connection Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }       
        return connect; 
    }
}
```

And now, in another class I succeeded to print my values but when I attempt to insert a value nothing is happening ...

Here's my code :

```
try {
Statement state = SQLConnection.getInstance().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
Statement state2 = SQLConnection.getInstance().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
state2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table(field1) VALUES (\"Value\")"); // Here's my problem
ResultSet res = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table");
```

Comment: I wonder why and how you tagged this as `prepared-statement` while you aren't using it in your code at all (you *should* however do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [commit](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit%28%29) (and [close](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29)) the connection (and statement) after use. You also need to ensure that you aren't swallowing any `SQLException`s which may cause that you see "nothing" to happen.

---

That said,

```
private static Connection connect;
```

This is a terribly bad idea. You should never declare *external* resources as `static` in your application. Your application will break when the other side decides to close the resource because it's been released for a too long time. You really need to acquire *and* close those resources (`Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` in the **shortest possible scope**. I.e. inside the very same method block as where the query is to be executed.

Also, I strongly recommend to use [`PreparedStatement`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of `Statement` since that will prevent your code from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [attacks](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).

You may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) useful to learn more about how to do basic JDBC interaction the right way.

Comment: Default is for autocommit to be on.  Unless you override it, there's no need to do commit call.  Close is also not strictly necessary (since it'll close on it's own anyways eventually), but it IS a best practice.

Comment: @Brian: In the years I've done JDBC I've learnt that there are only 2 possible causes for a query not being executed. 1) Connection is not committed. 2) An exception is swallowed. The OP might not have posted all the necessary information in the question (also see the other answers, they were based on misinformation from the OP).

Answer (score 1):

```
state2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table(field1) VALUES (\"Value\")");
```

should be:

```
state2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO plateau(field1) VALUES (\"Value\")");
```

Comment: Yes sorry I modified my code just for stackoverflow . The error is not that ;) (I edited my code)

Answer (score 0):

Copuld just be a copy over to SO error, but looking but shoulding INSERT INTO table(field1) be INSERT INTO plateau(field1)?

Comment: Yes sorry I modified my code just for stackoverflow . The error is not that ;) (I edited my code)